# Problem in scrolling of bottom sheet in android

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

My problem with bottom sheet in Android is that when I am scrolling up the sheet it fills the whole activity.
I need my bottom sheet to come to a stop at a certain height.

Below is my code:

activity_main.xml:-

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click here"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="272dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<include
    layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_height="79dp" />
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayour);
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(linearLayout);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(200);


}
```

Below is my bottom_sheet.xml file:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
android:id="@+id/linearlayour"

app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Inside bottom" />
```

I need my bottom sheet to come to stop at a certain height. I am not able to make it work like that. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include your bottomsheet layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CollapsingLayout above your main layout like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And then put your scrolling layout with the attribute -

```
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the peekHeight attribute of the bottomsheet to set the maximum height to which it can scroll max

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="200dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_content_view" />
</FrameLayout>
```